# wkhtmltopdf: download a PDF to the user's HD

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

how to download automaticaly (to the user's HD) a pdf generated using [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) or [snappy](https://github.com/knplabs/snappy)? You know.. a user click a link ("Download this page as PDF") and download the pdf to his/her HD.

Regards

Javi

Comment: Are you asking how to force a download rather than simply open the file in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I do it in RoR

```
filename = "MyNew.pdf"
fullpath = "#{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/charts/#{filename}"
# system issues a shell command
system "/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf \"http://localhost/page/to/pdf?download=t\" #{fullpath}"

send_data(File.read(fullpath), :type => 'application/pdf', :filename => filename, :disposition => "attachment;filename=\"#{filename}\"")
```

Answer (score 3):

PHP: there are better ways of getting wkhtmltopdf working with PHP, however, I like to be able to print out what my command line is so that I can debug the resulting page that bit more easily. It is not just about code, but about having margins and other page details correct. Here the wkhtmltopdf is a binary in the web root, margins are set to zero, the background is turned off:

```
$do_it=$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/wkhtmltopdf --dpi 600 -B 0 -L 0 -R 0 -T 0 --no-background http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/".$filename." ".$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/".$pdf_url;
//var_dump($do_it); // uncomment to see your wkhtmltopdf parameters...
$whatever=passthru($do_it);
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$pdf_url);
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
readfile($pdf_url);
```

I don't think much comes back when running passthru when it comes to error messages, however, it does run whatever you send it.
As for header, it is important to set the content type to PDF or else the browser will not know what to do with it.

The [Snappy website](https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy) actually also has a ready made example just for this.

```
$snappy = new Pdf('/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.pdf"');
echo $snappy->getOutput('http://www.github.com');
```